# How to call classmethod of base class from derived class when base class itself is inheriting from another library class (ndb.Model)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I know questions related to classmethods in python have been answered many times, but even after implementing those solutions, the problem I'm facing still persists.

I came across many answers which really helped me understand the base logic but due to the `ndb.Model` implementation here, I'm finding it hard to pinpoint the issue.

My code structure,

```
class A(ndb.Model):
    @classmethod
    def fun(cls, input):
        db_obj = cls.get_by_id(input) # get_by_id is ndb.Model function that brings record from db
        return db_obj.required_data 

class B(A):
    @classmethod
    def fun(cls, input):
        required_data = super(B, cls).fun(input)
```

When we reach to `cls.get_by_id(input)`, nothing is returned from DB even when the required record is present. When I don't make the derived class `fun()` as classmethod and call it directly like `A.fun()`, it then works. But, this would not be the correct implementation I believe.

Any help with the above would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Please try to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem. See if you can demonstrate the problem without involving a database. See if you can demonstrate the problem with your own grandparent class instead of `ndb.Model`. See if you can do anything else to narrow it down. Also try reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ .

Comment: You don't return the result of the call to `super` in `B.fun`?

Answer (score 1):

Is the datastore entity that you are trying to retrieve an A entity or a B entity?

I suspect it is a B entity since you are starting the process with `B.fun()`.

If that is the case, then the `get_by_id` in `A.fun()` won't work because it is trying to retrieve an A entity.  The `cls` in `A.fun()` is A and not B and thus it is trying to get an A entity that doesn't exist.

A solution could be to modify A.fun to also take a parameter that indicates the type of entity to retrieve.  This could be the class or just a string.  Something like this:

```
class A(ndb.Model):
    @classmethod
    def fun(cls, input, cls2):
        db_obj = cls2.get_by_id(input) # get_by_id is ndb.Model function that brings record from db
        return db_obj.required_data 

class B(A):
    @classmethod
    def fun(cls, input):
        required_data = super(B, cls).fun(input, cls)
```

Comment: This doesn't directly solve my problem but I learned that we can pass cls2 and use it to access the fn. This makes a lot of other things clear. Cannot accept this as the answer because it can be misleading to other users visiting this question. Thanks a lot for the above answer :)